# Fragment is not showing

Tags: android, android-fragments

The problem is a bit weird and complex - sometimes (it is not deterministic or I do not know the cause) some of my fragments are not showing up in transaction.

I checked everything twice, and it seems OK - fragment is correctly added before, is not null etc., has field `mHidden` set to `true` before and to `false` after the transaction, but all I see is an empty place.

What could be wrong?

To be more precise about the problem - I'm managing many fragments in one `Activity` (up to 25) at the same time, and the transactions hide / show many of them at once. What's more, I have 4 fragments added to the same layout holder (`FrameLayout`), and switching their visibility - but I don't think it may be the cause.

I'm starting to hate Android...

Comment: Could you add the most important parts of your code as well as the xml layouts you are using?

Comment: I wish I could, but my app is like 20k lines of code and is very complex and I have no idea where's the clue - all my fragments have `RelativeLayout` as the root and are dynamically added into `FrameLayout` holders as I mentioned. Most of the time transactions are fine (what is prove they are OK), but sometimes such situation happens... So this is rather general question, like "what could cause the fragment not to be shown in the transaction, although all seems to be OK".

Answer (score 1):

OK, it's wonderful how often you come up with a solution while showing your problem to the others - the problem here was in hide / show animations - there was a use case when I was hiding a fragment with some kind of animation (scale to 0.0, fade, etc.) and later (special case) show it without an enter reverse animation (as an optimization) - fragment WAS shown, but remain scaled to 0 or faded.