# Fragment not showing View after transistion

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I have an activity which left and Right fragment,Based on click of leftSide fragment,Elements in right Side of fragment is replaced.

But the problem I am facing is,If i give any animation during transition,Fragment which is to be shown ,its oncreate method is called,But View  is coming empty.

But,Only in One activity,It is loaded successfully,I am trying to sort whether it is problem with XML.If it is problem with XML,It should be not loading in one fragment.

My Problem is same as specified like below

[Fragment is not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383797/fragment-is-not-showing)

Comment: Has any one faced similar sort of issue.I am using native fragments instead of support Library since I am supporting 3.0 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've added the fragment to the activity's XML file
You should find a fragment tag similar to this but with your fragment name:

```
<fragment
    android:name= "com.example.THE_PATH_TO_YOUR_FRAGMENT"
       .........
        .........
         .........  />
```